# SQL Server CDC Invalid column name __$command_id

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have enabled CDC in a source database and created following packages.

1. Initial Load(CDC start -->Data flow ---> CDC end)
2. Incremental load(CDC start(get processing range) --> data flow -->cdc end (mark processing end)

These package run perfectly fine when i am running manually, but I am getting the following error message while running thru a scheduled job.

> Data Flow Task:Error: "Problems when trying to get changed records
>   from dbo_AddonQuote. Reson-Invald column name '__&command_id"

Here is the cdc state value

```
ILUPDATE/CS/0x0000053600005CFD0002/CE/0x000005360000604F0004/IR/0x0000053600005CFD0002/0x0000053600005D140002/TS/2018-03-22T23:10:22.5173580/
```

As I told before this is not happening while I run manually.

Can anyone shed some light on whats happening here? or how to debug this issue?

Comment: SQL Server build number / version?

Comment: sql server 2016, Version 14.0.25431.01

Comment: @Siva, that's Visual Studio build. Can you get MS SQL build? SELECT @@version

Comment: @anton, here is the ms sql build version
Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1-CU4) (KB4024305) - 13.0.4446.0 (X64)   Jul 16 2017 18:08:49

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following change fixed my issue.

My old package
Get Processing --> Data flow --> Mark processed

Updated Package
CDC start --> Get processing --> Data flow --> Mark processed

Here is the reference link which explains about the issue
http://www.bradleyschacht.com/understanding-the-cdc-state-value/

Answer (score 2):

I was the one who asked MS to add that column because I discovered a few CDC bugs. They added that column, but they did it in incorrect / inconsistent way.

Recently they released new CUs to fix a few CDC bugs, one was (likely) for your issue. Download the latest CU for your version or/and try to execute

sp_cdc_vupgrade

against the database enabled for CDC.

Before that, check

- if your capture instance (cdc.dbo_AddonQuote_CT) has that column (__$command_id)
- if CDC stored procedures ([cdc].[sp_batchinsert_xxxxx]) refer that column
- if CDC functions ([cdc].[fn_cdc_get_net_changes_dbo_xxxxx) refer that column

BTW. We don't use SSIS CDC Data flow. It's better to create own solution. MS CDC get net changes functions are very slow in certain scenarios and in certain scenarios they return incorrect results. If you create your own methods to read the data from capture instances, it will be more reliable and faster.

Comment: The following change fixed my issue.  
Instead of
Get Processing --> Data flow --> Mark processed  
I have updated my package like below  
Mark Start --> Get processsing --> data flow --> Mark processed

Reference link --> http://www.bradleyschacht.com/understanding-the-cdc-state-value/

Answer (score 0):

None of the above solutions worked for me.
I'm using MS SQL 2017 with latest CU15.

I the end I didn't use CDC start in SSIS but I found official solution in Microsoft DWH certification materials which is also working ok only if you're not using CDC start.

Following example shows how to change:
`cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes` and   `cdc.fn_cdc_get_net_changes` in order to avoid such problems in SSIS.

**You need to chang `__$command_id` column to `NULL` for every value.**

Here it is for `[HumanResources]` demo database with only one table called `Employee`. No other changes needed. Just run this for your db/table and your CDC in SSIS will work without any other modifications needed.

```
USE [HumanResources]
GO

EXEC sp_rename N'cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_dbo_Employee', N'fn_cdc_get_all_changes_dbo_Employee_safe'
GO

CREATE FUNCTION cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_dbo_Employee(
     @from_lsn BINARY(10),
     @to_lsn BINARY(10), 
     @row_filter_option NVARCHAR(30))
 RETURNS TABLE

 RETURN SELECT *, NULL AS __$command_id
        FROM cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_dbo_Employee_safe(
            @from_lsn,
            @to_lsn,
            @row_filter_option)
GO

EXEC sp_rename N'cdc.fn_cdc_get_net_changes_dbo_Employee', N'fn_cdc_get_net_changes_dbo_Employee_safe'
GO

CREATE FUNCTION cdc.fn_cdc_get_net_changes_dbo_Employee (
     @from_lsn BINARY(10), 
     @to_lsn BINARY(10),
     @row_filter_option NVARCHAR(30))
  RETURNS TABLE

  RETURN SELECT *, NULL AS __$command_id
         FROM cdc.fn_cdc_get_net_changes_dbo_Employee_safe (
             @from_lsn,
             @to_lsn,
             @row_filter_option)
GO
```

Comment: @Harvey- do you have any reference link to understand this solution?

Comment: @Siva this is official MS fix present in materials for  Implementing a Data Warehouse Using SQL. 70-768 certification. I saw it there as script, run it, and problems were fixed. I try to find explanation for that in course materials but couldn't find single reference to it. I can only assume that implementation of __$command_id was poorly implemented and that this is workaround for that.